# Flesch Readability Index in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a program that is supposed to perform the calculations for the Flesch Readability Index. The program is supposed to read in a text file "Project7.txt", it's then supposed to display the text in a multi-line text box and perform the following calculations:

1. Count the number of words in the file.
2. Count the number of syllables in the file.
3. Count the number of sentences in the file (a sentence can be ended by a ".", "?", "!", or ":"

The program is then supposed to plug the values into the following formula and display the result in a label (label1).

```
206.835-85.6*(Number of syllables/Number of words) - 1.015*(Number of words/Number of sentences)
```

Here is the code I have written so far.

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim open As New OpenFileDialog

        open.Filter = "text files |project7.txt|All file |*.*"
        open.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)

        If open.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim selectedFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(open.FileName)
            If selectedFileName.ToLower = "project7.txt" Then
                Dim doc As String = ""
                Dim line As String
                Using reader As New StreamReader(open.OpenFile)
                    While Not reader.EndOfStream
                        doc += reader.ReadLine
                        Console.WriteLine(line)
                    End While
                    Dim text = File.ReadAllText("Project7.txt")
                    Dim words = text.Split(" "c)
                    Dim wordCount = words.Length
                    Dim separators As Char() = {"."c, "!"c, "?"c, ":"c}
                    Dim sentences = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    Dim sentenceCount = sentences.Length
                End Using
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot use that file!")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Function CountSyllables(word As String) As Integer
        word = word.ToLower()
        Dim dipthongs = {"oo", "ou", "ie", "oi", "ea", "ee", _
                     "eu", "ai", "ua", "ue", "au", "io"}
        For Each dipthong In dipthongs
            word = word.Replace(dipthong, dipthong(0))
        Next
        Dim vowels = "aeiou"
        Dim vowelCount = 0
        For Each c In word
            If vowels.IndexOf(c) >= 0 Then vowelCount += 1
        Next
        Return vowelCount
    End Function

End Class
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code always reporting one more sentence than there actually is?

If so take a look at this from the [`String.Split` method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) docs:

> When the Split function encounters two delimiters in a row, or a
>   delimiter at the beginning or end of the string, it interprets them as
>   surrounding an empty string ("")...

I'm sure your last sentence ends with your sentence delimiter so what's happening is your assignment to `sentences` is getting an extra, empty array element.  See for yourself by breakpointing the line after your assignment and hovering your mouse over `sentences`. Examine the contents of the array.

The fix is to call `Split` with the option to remove empty array values.  To do that though you'll need to call the `Split` overload that takes an array of `Char` for the delimiters:

Replace this line:

```
Dim sentences = text.Split("."c, "!"c, "?"c, ":"c)
```

With this:

```
Dim separators As Char() = {"."c, "!"c, "?"c, ":"c}
Dim sentences = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

And you should be good.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you that corrected the issue I was having with the sentence count. Now just to figure out how to do the rest of it ha.